# add_query_arg not working

Tags: plugins, php, functions, filters

I added a filter to append a parameter onto the URL when navigating in categories. This is used to sort posts by their votes when browsing a category only if a `sort` parameter is set.

For instance when you click view all posts with most votes, posts with high votes are displayed. From there you can view most voted posts by category by appending a `sort=most_voted` or `sort=doleast_voted` to the URL with `cat=?`.

```
add_filter( 'category_link','append_parameter', 10, 2 );

function append_parameter( $link, $query ) {
$my_parameter = $query->query_vars['sort']; //get sort value
if ( isset($my_parameter) ) { //if browsing posts by votes
    $link = add_query_arg( 'sort', $my_parameter, $link );
}
    return $link;
}
```

I can't figure out why the sort parameter isn't appended to the URL. This works however without the if statements and a value instead of the `$my_parameter` in the add_query_arg.

EDIT: New working code

```
    add_filter( 'category_link','append_parameter', 10, 2 );

    function append_parameter( $link, $my_parameter ) {
    $my_parameter = $_GET['sort']; //get sort value       
    if ( isset($my_parameter) ) { 
        $link = add_query_arg( 'sort', $my_parameter, $link );
    }
        return $link;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look where the `category_link` hook is defined in [category-template.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L18) you'll see this particular hook passes on two variables. The second variable is the category ID, but your callback function treats that second incoming variable as a query object.

Simply put, you're looking for a `query_vars` property/key that does not and cannot exist, because the incoming variable is not a query object.

Comment: thank you for the info! Not sure if I'm on the same page. Hopefully this is relevant to your answer.. I'm not getting any query object related errors. I use the same approach in other functions. The `$query` argument is for `$_GET["sort"]` which checks the value of my `sort` parameter that I added with a `query_vars` filter. If for instance `$_GET["sort"] = "most_voted"` I want to display all posts with high votes within any category.

Comment: My point being, the second variable in your function `$query` is not a query object.. it's a category ID passed along from the filter your function is hooked onto(the filter hook sets what is in this variable).

Comment: Ahh thanks for explaining!! I guess the second query is ideal for post filters.. I added a new working code in my answer. I think I'm on the right track now :)

Comment: If you're not going to use the value being passed into that second variable, just drop it from the filter..   NOTE: You should ideally check a var is set **before storing it** in a variable(i'd suggest writing your plugins with WP_DEBUG enabled).

Comment: That's a very valuable suggestion. I'll definitely enable WP_DEBUG now that you mentioned it.